# How do I break a string into words and track the index of each word (within the original string)?

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
const str = 'a string, a long string'
```

I want to break it down into words (no problem here) and then track the index of each word within the original string.

Actual result:

```
[
  { word: 'a',      idx: 0 },
  { word: 'string', idx: 2 },
  { word: 'a',      idx: 0 },
  { word: 'long',   idx: 12 },
  { word: 'string', idx: 2 }
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
  { word: 'a',      idx: 0 },
  { word: 'string', idx: 2 },
  { word: 'a',      idx: 10 },
  { word: 'long',   idx: 12 },
  { word: 'string', idx: 17 }
]
```

Code so far:

```js
const str = 'a string, a long string'

const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter([], { granularity: 'word' })

const getWords = str => {
  const segments = segmenter.segment(str)
  return [...segments]
    .filter(s => s.isWordLike)
    .map(s => s.segment)
}

const words = getWords(str)

const result = words.map(word => ({
  word,
  idx: str.indexOf(word)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the index in each segment, instead of trying to find that word again afterwards?

Comment: Could setting an empty array instead of `en` explicitly in `Intl.Segmenter` have unintended consequences? Won't it use the locale of the persons browser?

Comment: You'd need to make use of `indexOf()`'s second parameter, the start index, to make sure you move past the last occurrence - but I don't think there's a way to fit that into your very concise bit of code.  You may have to slum it with a bit of old-school Javascript, such as the replace-found-words-with-symbols-to-avoid-finding-same-occurrence technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects you're iterating over, which contain the `segment` and whether or not it `isWordLike`, **also have the `index`**:

```js
const str = 'a string, a long string'

const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter([], { granularity: 'word' })

const getWordsWithIndexes = str => {
  const segments = segmenter.segment(str)
  return [...segments]
    .filter(s => s.isWordLike)
    .map(s => ({ idx: s.index, word: s.segment }))
}

const result = getWordsWithIndexes(str)

console.log(result)
```

Here's the [type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cea0b61320ee69ae863cc9d7bf873113eb420e3b/src/lib/es2022.intl.d.ts#L43-L55):

```typescript
interface SegmentData {
    /** A string containing the segment extracted from the original input string. */
    segment: string;
    /** The code unit index in the original input string at which the segment begins. */
    index: number;
    /** The complete input string that was segmented. */
    input: string;
    /**
     * A boolean value only if granularity is "word"; otherwise, undefined.
     * If granularity is "word", then isWordLike is true when the segment is word-like (i.e., consists of letters/numbers/ideographs/etc.); otherwise, false.
     */
    isWordLike?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an idea to use [`String.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to retrieve words and indexes.

Or just reduce the `Intl.Segmenter.segment` result.

Something like:

```js
const str = 'a string, a long string';

console.log(getWordStartIndexes(str));
console.log(segment2Words(str));

function getWordStartIndexes(str) {
   return [...str.matchAll(/(\p{L}+?)([\p{Z}\p{P}]|$)/gu)]
    .map( match => ({word: match[1], index: match.index }) );
   
}

function segment2Words(str) {
  return [...new Intl.Segmenter([], { granularity: 'word' }).segment(str)]
    .reduce( (acc, {segment, index, isWordLike}) => 
      isWordLike ? [...acc, {word: segment, index}] : acc, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regex, it's 25x faster than a Segmenter:

```js
const result = [];
'a string, a long string'.replace(/\w+/g, (word, idx) => result.push({word, idx}));

result.forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

```
` Chrome/120
---------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander           1.00x  |  x1000000  234  239  240  245  246
cached Segmenter   26.79x  |   x100000  627  636  643  650  663
Segmenter          71.79x  |    x10000  168  169  170  171  177
---------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter([], { granularity: 'word' })

// @benchmark Segmenter
{
const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter([], { granularity: 'word' })

const getWordsWithIndexes = str => {
  const segments = segmenter.segment(str)
  return [...segments]
    .filter(s => s.isWordLike)
    .map(s => ({ idx: s.index, word: s.segment }))
}

getWordsWithIndexes('a string, a long string');
}

// @benchmark cached Segmenter
{
const getWordsWithIndexes = str => {
  const segments = segmenter.segment(str)
  return [...segments]
    .filter(s => s.isWordLike)
    .map(s => ({ idx: s.index, word: s.segment }))
}

getWordsWithIndexes('a string, a long string');
}

// @benchmark Alexander
const result = [];
'a string, a long string'.replace(/\w+/g, (word, idx) => result.push({word, idx}));
result;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: The second word in you regexp-solution will be 'string,' (so it will not remove the comma).

Comment: Better ;) Still, won't match unicode: check `'a string, a löng ßtring'.match(/\w+/g)`

Comment: Anyway, you're right that `RegExp` is [way faster](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ewdc9z?file=index.js) vs`Intl.Segmenter`

Comment: @KooiInc we could have a unicode matching in a regex too, i just didn't bother since a potentially accepted answer was obvious from the beginning. Btw you can try my benchmark tool to avoid manual benchmark coding, it even supports several benchmark groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828008/find-repeat-sequence-in-an-array/77833257#77833257

Comment: @KooiInc it automatically estimates number of cycles, you just write different code pieces and click 'Run'

Answer (score -2):

I decomposed your string into an array of object containing the word and the word index.

```
const str = 'a string, a long string';

const words = str.split(' ').map((word, index) => ({ word, index }));

console.log(words)
```

If you want the punctuation as a word you could use a regex.

```
const words = str.split(/\s+|(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})/u).map((word, index) => ({ word, index }));
```