# Longest Repeating Subarray (With Overlapping)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of arbitrary numbers, I am looking to quickly [with time and space complexity lower than O(n²) at minimum, n = length of array] find the longest subarray (a contiguous segment of elements within array) that is repeated (appears more than once, or at least twice).
Please don't assume any bounds on the numbers in the array apart from all the values are valid JavaScript numbers and `isFinite` is true for every number in the array.

Overlapping is allowed, that is partial occurrences of a subarray within itself is allowed. for ex, in the array `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` the longest repeating subarray is `[1, 2, 1, 2]`. Look here

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
^         ^        occurrence #1
       ^        ^  occurrence #2
```

The two occurrences overlap, but that is a-ok as long as the two occurrence differ in either starting or ending index.

In case there are multiple distinct repeated subarrays that all have the longest length, the answer can be any of them. However, I suspect that any way that can find one answer can find all of them with the same ease.
A sample for this scenario is the array `[1, 1, 2, 2]`. The subarray `[1]` and `[2]` both appear twice. Either of those may be returned as the result.

Finally, if no subarray occurs more than once, the answer is `[]` (the empty array).

I recently came across the question [Find Repeat Sequence in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828008/find-repeat-sequence-in-an-array) but all the answers there are ridiculously slow. Everyone's using o(n³) solutions, with only one answer in o(n²).

I'm seeking a method that can handle arrays with length up to a couple hundred thousand (100,000) in a few seconds. Sub quadratic time complexity at least. It'd be great if you can provide a sample implementation in JS of the solution too because my understanding of some data structures is not that solid

Sorry for the long question, let me know if anything is unclear. If you have an idea but not a full solution just drop it in the comments, it can still be helpful to me.

I made some more examples if it helps:

| Array | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `[1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5]` | `[1, 2]` |
| `[9, 7, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 8, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3]` | `[1, 6, 3]` |
| `[1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 0, -1, 7, 0, -1]` | `[7, 0, -1]` |
| `[1, 1, 1, 1]` | `[1, 1, 1]` |
| `[1, 1, 1]` | `[1, 1]` |
| `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]` | `[2]` |
| `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` | `[]` |
| `[1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 5]` | `[1, 6, 2, 1]` |

Here's a function to generate large test case with array size 100,000 for reference, the answer is [1, 2, 3, ..., 100] (the 100 consecutive integers from 1 to 100)

```
function make_case() {
    let array = [];
    let number = 200;
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < (100_000 - 500 * 2 - 100 - 1700 * 2 - 100) / 2; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Another important case is `new Array(100_000).fill(0)`, the answer is the array with 99,999 zeros.

Comment: Just want to see if there are other solutions to this problem too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved by building a suffix array over a general alphabet. The longest repeating subarray will be the longest common prefix (LCP) between some two adjacent elements in the suffix array.

The following method has a time complexity of O(N log^2 (N)) and space complexity of O(N). The running time is dominated by the creation of the suffix array, so it can optimized further by using a faster suffix array construction algorithm, e.g. DC3.

```js
function longestRepeatingSubarray(arr) {
    const n = arr.length, suff = [...arr.keys()], rank = [...arr], lcp = Array(n), tempRank = Array(n);
    tempRank[0] = 0;
    for (let jump = 1; jump < n; jump <<= 1) {
        const comp = (i, j) => rank[i] - rank[j] || (Math.max(i, j) + jump < n ? rank[i + jump] - rank[j + jump] : j - i);
        suff.sort(comp);
        for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) tempRank[i] = tempRank[i - 1] + !!comp(suff[i - 1], suff[i]);
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) rank[suff[i]] = tempRank[i];
    }
    for (let i = 0, k = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (rank[i] !== n - 1) {
            for (let j = suff[rank[i] + 1]; arr[i + k] === arr[j + k];) ++k;
            lcp[rank[i]] = k;
            if (k) --k;
        }
    let best = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) if (lcp[i] > lcp[best]) best = i;
    return arr.slice(suff[best], suff[best] + lcp[best]);
}

console.log(...longestRepeatingSubarray([1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5]));
console.log(...longestRepeatingSubarray([1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 0, -1, 7, 0, -1]));
function make_case(){let $=[],u=200;for(let e=0;e<500;e++)$.push(u),$.push(u),u++;for(let s=1;s<101;s++)$.push(s);for(let h=0;h<1700;h++)$.push(u),$.push(u),u++;for(let p=1;p<101;p++)$.push(p);for(let t=0;t<47700;t++)$.push(u),$.push(u),u++;return $}
const arr = make_case();
console.time(`${arr.length} elements`);
console.log(...longestRepeatingSubarray(arr));
console.timeEnd(`${arr.length} elements`);
```

Comment: this is cool but I don't get how it works. I'll come back to it later

Answer (score 3):

The longest repeating subarray is the deepest non-leaf node in the [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or, equivalently, the longest common prefix between adjacent nodes in the [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array).

Generating the suffix array with a radix sort finds the longest common prefix as a side effect, in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.  This is the easiest solution that meets your requirements.

The suffix tree can be built in O(n) time, revealing the answer, using [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english).  This is pretty difficult and complicated, however.

The linked Wikipedia page on suffix arrays points to some O(n) algorithms for those, too.  I'm not super familiar with any of them but they are also kind of hard to grok.

An easy (expected) O(n log n) solution is to do a binary search for the largest length of 2 matching substrings, checking each length using a [Rabin-Karp-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) rolling hash.

Comment: I'm going to try doing some of these suggestions but there doesn't seem to be good JS examples to look at

Answer (score -1):

You can use loops:

```
var solve = (input) => {
    var ans, s, s2, ii, _ans
    s = 0
    ans = []
    while (s < input.length) {
        s2 = s + 1
        while (s2 < input.length) {
            ii = 0
            _ans = []
            while (ii + s2 < input.length) {
                if (input[s+ii] != input[s2+ii]) {
                    break
                } else {
                    _ans.push(input[s+ii])
                    ii++
                }
            }
            if (ii > ans.length) {
                console.log(s, s2, ii, _ans)
                ans = _ans
            }
            s2++
        }
        s++
    }
    return ans
}
```

(Disclaimer: not tested. But it should work.)

Comment: This requires cubic time in the worst case — and, in fact, quadratic time in the best case.

Comment: *"not tested. But it should work"* -  very troubling

Comment: @Spectric: Really? I think that's fine, as long as the answerer has good reason to think the approach works. After all, the OP can always test the code before adopting it. No less a luminary than Donald Knuth once wrote, "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Comment: @ruakh: But unless one actually is Donald Knuth, it's probably a good idea to test the code (when possible) before presenting it as an answer...

Comment: And maybe adding some explanations, not just "you can use loops"